# Outlook VBA Most Recent Email in Chain Condition

Tags: vba, outlook

I am attempting to write Outlook VBA code to do the following:

Loop through emails in the Outlook inbox that were received within the past 96 hours and meet certain criteria.

Save attachments of emails that meet criteria.

I am having trouble creating a condition to only consider the most recent email in each thread.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveXYZAttachments()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim SaveFolder As String
    Dim OrderNumber As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim attachmentSaved As Boolean ' Flag to track if any attachment is saved
    
    ' Set the save folder path
    SaveFolder = "C:\Users\a123456\OneDrive - ORG\FILES - Paddy's Orders v2\"
    
    ' Set the Outlook objects
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox
    
    ' Loop through the items in the folder
    For Each Item In SubFolder.items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" & _
        Format(DateAdd("h", -96, Now()), "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' AND ([SenderEmailAddress] = 'email1@yahoo.com' OR [SenderEmailAddress] = 'email2@yahoo.com')")
        
        ' Check if the email subject contains "Identifying Header 1" and the body contains "Identifying Body Text"
        If InStr(1, Item.Subject, "Identifying Header 1", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, Item.Body, "Identifying Body Text", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Process attachments for Identifying Header 1 condition
            OrderNumber = Trim(Mid(Item.Subject, InStr(Item.Subject, "Order#") + 6, 9))
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
                    FileName = OrderNumber & " NAME 1 " & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MM.dd") & ".pdf"
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & FileName
                    attachmentSaved = True
                    Debug.Print "Saved File: " & SaveFolder & FileName
                End If
            Next Atmt
            Debug.Print "Skipped Email (Identifying Header 1): " & Item.Subject
        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "Identifying Header 2", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, Item.Body, "Identifying Body Text", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Process attachments for Identifying Header 2 condition
            OrderNumber = Trim(Mid(Item.Subject, InStr(Item.Subject, "Order#") + 6, 9))
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
                    FileName = OrderNumber & " NAME 2 " & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MM.dd") & ".pdf"
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & FileName
                    attachmentSaved = True
                    Debug.Print "Saved File: " & SaveFolder & FileName
                End If
            Next Atmt
            Debug.Print "Skipped Email (Identifying Header 2): " & Item.Subject
        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "Identifying Header 3", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, Item.Body, "Identifying Body Text", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Process attachments for Identifying Header 3 condition
            OrderNumber = Trim(Mid(Item.Subject, InStr(Item.Subject, "Order#") + 6, 9))
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
                    FileName = OrderNumber & " NAME 3 " & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MM.dd") & ".pdf"
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & FileName
                    attachmentSaved = True
                    Debug.Print "Saved File: " & SaveFolder & FileName
                End If
            Next Atmt
            Debug.Print "Skipped Email (Identifying Header 3): " & Item.Subject
        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Body, "Dif Identifying Word 1", vbTextCompare) > 0 And (InStr(1, Item.Body, "Dif Identifying Word 2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, Item.Body, "Dif Identifying Word 3", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            ' Process attachments for body content condition
            OrderNumber = Trim(Mid(Item.Subject, InStr(Item.Subject, "Order#") + 6, 9))
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
                        ' Determine the naming convention based on the subject line
                        Dim namingConvention As String
                        If InStr(1, Item.Subject, "Identifying Header 1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            namingConvention = "OTHER NAME 1"
                        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "Identifying Header 2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            namingConvention = "OTHER NAME 2"
                        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "Identifying Header 3", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            namingConvention = "OTHER NAME 3"
                        Else
                            namingConvention = "BLAH"
                        End If
                        FileName = OrderNumber & " " & namingConvention & " " & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MM.dd") & ".pdf"
                        Atmt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & FileName
                        attachmentSaved = True
                        Debug.Print "Saved File: " & SaveFolder & FileName
                    Else
                        Debug.Print "Skipped Attachment: " & Atmt.FileName
                    End If
                End If
            Next Atmt
        End If
    Next Item
    
    If attachmentSaved Then
        MsgBox "Attachments downloaded successfully."
    Else
        MsgBox "No emails met specified conditions, no attachments saved."
    End If
    
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub
```

I tried adding an 'IsMostRecentEmail' function:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveDSVAttachments()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim SaveFolder As String
    Dim OrderNumber As String
    Dim attachmentSaved As Boolean ' Flag to track if any attachment is saved
    
    ' Set the save folder path
    SaveFolder = "C:\Users\a562455\OneDrive - Valvoline\FILES - Paddy's Orders v2\"
    
    ' Set the Outlook objects
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox
    
    ' Loop through the items in the folder
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" & _
        Format(DateAdd("h", -96, Now()), "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' AND ([SenderEmailAddress] = 'mandy.russell@us.dsv.com' OR [SenderEmailAddress] = 'kyle.patrick@dsv.com')")
        
        ' Check if the email subject contains "DSV SEA US/GT" and the body contains "booking confirmation"
        If InStr(1, Item.Subject, "DSV SEA US/GT", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, Item.Body, "booking confirmation", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Process attachments for DSV SEA US/GT condition
            OrderNumber = Trim(Mid(Item.Subject, InStr(Item.Subject, "Order#") + 6, 9))
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
                    FileName = OrderNumber & " BKG LUISA " & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MM.dd") & ".pdf"
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & FileName
                    attachmentSaved = True
                    Debug.Print "Saved File: " & SaveFolder & FileName
                End If
            Next Atmt
            Debug.Print "Skipped Email (DSV SEA US/GT): " & Item.Subject
        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "DSV SEA US/HN", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, Item.Body, "booking confirmation", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Process attachments for DSV SEA US/HN condition
            OrderNumber = Trim(Mid(Item.Subject, InStr(Item.Subject, "Order#") + 6, 9))
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
                    FileName = OrderNumber & " BKG REASA " & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MM.dd") & ".pdf"
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & FileName
                    attachmentSaved = True
                    Debug.Print "Saved File: " & SaveFolder & FileName
                End If
            Next Atmt
            Debug.Print "Skipped Email (DSV SEA US/HN): " & Item.Subject
        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "DSV SEA US/NI", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, Item.Body, "booking confirmation", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Process attachments for DSV SEA US/NI condition
            OrderNumber = Trim(Mid(Item.Subject, InStr(Item.Subject, "Order#") + 6, 9))
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
                    FileName = OrderNumber & " BKG AUTOMASTER " & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MM.dd") & ".pdf"
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & FileName
                    attachmentSaved = True
                    Debug.Print "Saved File: " & SaveFolder & FileName
                End If
            Next Atmt
            Debug.Print "Skipped Email (DSV SEA US/NI): " & Item.Subject
        ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Body, "attached", vbTextCompare) > 0 And (InStr(1, Item.Body, "BL", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, Item.Body, "bl", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            ' Check if the email is the most recent in the thread
            If IsMostRecentEmail(Item) Then
                ' Process attachments for most recent email condition
                OrderNumber = Trim(Mid(Item.Subject, InStr(Item.Subject, "Order#") + 6, 9))
                For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                    If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
                        ' Check if the attachment contains "AES" in the name
                        If InStr(1, Atmt.FileName, "AES", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            ' Determine the naming convention based on the subject line
                            Dim namingConvention As String
                            If InStr(1, Item.Subject, "DSV SEA US/GT", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                                namingConvention = "BL LUISA"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "DSV SEA US/HN", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                                namingConvention = "BL REASA"
                            ElseIf InStr(1, Item.Subject, "DSV SEA US/NI", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                                namingConvention = "BL AUTOMASTER"
                            Else
                                namingConvention = "BL"
                            End If
                            FileName = OrderNumber & " " & namingConvention & " " & Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MM.dd") & ".pdf"
                            Atmt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & FileName
                            attachmentSaved = True
                            Debug.Print "Saved File: " & SaveFolder & FileName
                        Else
                            Debug.Print "Skipped Attachment (Contains AES): " & Atmt.FileName
                        End If
                    End If
                Next Atmt
                Debug.Print "Skipped Email (Most Recent): " & Item.Subject
            Else
                Debug.Print "Skipped Email (Not Most Recent): " & Item.Subject
            End If
        End If
    Next Item
    
    If attachmentSaved Then
        MsgBox "Attachments downloaded successfully."
    Else
        MsgBox "No emails met specified conditions, no attachments saved."
    End If
    
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub

Private Function IsMostRecentEmail(ByVal email As Object) As Boolean
    Dim threadRoot As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim currentEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim emailThread As Outlook.Conversation
    Dim parentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim items As Outlook.Items
    Dim receivedTime As Date
    Dim item As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    If email Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    ' Get the parent folder of the email
    Set parentFolder = email.Parent
    
    ' Get the Conversation object of the email
    Set emailThread = email.GetConversation
    
    If Not emailThread Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the root email of the thread
        Set threadRoot = emailThread.GetRootItems.Item(1)
        
        ' Get the received time of the root email
        receivedTime = threadRoot.ReceivedTime
        
        ' Get the items in the parent folder
        Set items = parentFolder.Items
        
        ' Check if any item in the parent folder has a later received time
        For Each item In items
            If TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
                Set currentEmail = item
                If currentEmail.GetConversation Is emailThread Then
                    If currentEmail.ReceivedTime > receivedTime Then
                        IsMostRecentEmail = False
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next item
    End If
    
    IsMostRecentEmail = True
End Function
```

This code runs, but all attachments are saved according to the first set of conditions, even though some of them should be saved according to the second condition block. I suspect this is because earlier in the email thread, the conditions for the first block are met - which is why I want to only consider the most recent email to determine which attachments to download and what to name them.

Comment: The solution should likely include a sort. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort. The site has many examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you process mail in older to newer order the action on recent mail should overwrite the older.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveXYZAttachments()
    
    Dim Inbox As folder
    Dim SubFolder As folder
    
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim myItems As Items
    
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim SaveFolder As String
    Dim OrderNumber As String
    
    Dim attachmentSaved As Boolean ' Flag to track if any attachment is saved
    
    ' Set the save folder path
    SaveFolder = "C:\Users\a123456\OneDrive - ORG\FILES - Paddy's Orders v2\"
    
    ' Set the Outlook objects
    Set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox
    
    Set myItems = SubFolder.Items
    Debug.Print myItems.count
    
    ' Oldest first:
    ' Same as ItemAdd or NewMailEx
    myItems.Sort ("[ReceivedTime]"), False
    ' Action on newer items should overwrite action taken on older
    
    Dim strFilter As String
    
    strFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & _
      Format(DateAdd("h", -96, Now()), "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' AND ([SenderEmailAddress] = 'email1@yahoo.com' OR [SenderEmailAddress] = 'email2@yahoo.com')"
    
    ' simplified for testing
    'strFilter = "[ReceivedTime]>= '" & Format(DateAdd("h", -96, Now()), "DDDDD HH:NN AMPM") & "'"
    Debug.Print strFilter
    
    Dim resItems As Items
    Set resItems = myItems.Restrict(strFilter)
    Debug.Print resItems.count
    
    ' For Each in sorted order
    For Each myItem In resItems
        If myItem.Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print myItem.subject
            Debug.Print " " & myItem.ReceivedTime
            ' your code here
        End If
    Next
    
    If attachmentSaved Then
        MsgBox "Attachments downloaded successfully."
    Else
        MsgBox "No emails met specified conditions, no attachments saved."
    End If
    
End Sub
```